# SIGABORT issued when calling Android Java JNI GetDoubleField()

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am getting a SIGABORT when calling GetDoubleField().

I have written a small sample program to show the issue...

**MainActivity.java**

```
package net.directionalsystems.jnitest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

private static final String TAG = "Mainactivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

    JniComms jc = new JniComms();
    jc.latitude = 10;
    jc.logitude = 20;
    jc.txtLocation = "Hello";

    try {
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI(jc));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ", e);
    }
}

/**
 * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
 * which is packaged with this application.
 */
public native String stringFromJNI(JniComms jc);
```

}

**JniComms.java**

```
package net.directionalsystems.jnitest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JniComms
{
    public double latitude;
    public double logitude;
    public String txtLocation;
    //public ArrayList<BleStatus> bleStatusArray;

}
```

**native-lib.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_net_directionalsystems_jnitest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject jo,
        jobject jc)
        {

            jclass jcClass = env->GetObjectClass(jc);
            jfieldID iId = env->GetFieldID(jcClass, "latitude", "D");

            // Executing the next line causes SIGABORT
            jdouble latitude = env->GetDoubleField(jcClass, iId);

            std::string hello = "Hello world";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

**The build.gradle file follows...**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.directionalsystems.jnitest"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        customDebugType {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

This has got to be something simple and stupid that I am doing.

I would like to debug into the NDK code but all I get is the jni.h file displayed and cannot step into the JNI code itself. Having that capability may give me an idea of what is wrong.

Many thanks for any help.

Best regards, Jackie

Comment: What's the value of env pointer and iId in cpp code?

Comment: Shouldn't you use (*env) as in (*env)->GetFieldID rather than env->GetFieldID etc?

Comment: @cplusogl `env->` is correct for C++ code. `(*env)->` is the way you'd do it in C.

Comment: Both syntax are correct, no matter c or c++. If you're messing up pointer dereference or pointer to a pointer dereference then there will be a huge problem

Comment: _"Both syntax are correct, no matter c or c++."_ `(*env)->` is not valid for a `JNIEnv*` in C++. `JNIEnv` are defined as different types in C and C++.

Comment: Have you considered adding error checking to your code? You must error-check the result of every JNI call.

Comment: This piece of code is a “Mickey Mouse” i.e. cut down out of the real program hence I called a sample when I wrote it. The real version is multi-threaded and Does indeed have error checking and has FLIHs and STIs but would, therefore be unnecessarily complex to deal with what I knew was going to be a simple issue for someone, like Michael, who knows this interface to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

When reading an instance (non-static) field you're supposed to pass the object, not the class.

So replace:

```
jdouble latitude = env->GetDoubleField(jcClass, iId);
```

with:

```
jdouble latitude = env->GetDoubleField(jc, iId);
```

Comment: jc or jo object?

Comment: `jc`. The `jo` object is the `MainActivity` instance.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I knew it was something stupid that I had done.Replacing jcClass with jc does, indeed, fix the issue. Best regards Jackie

Comment: @Jackie And that is why you need to **always** check **all** return values in JNI.